# Circular Import error when trying to use flask-socket library

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, websocket, socket.io

I am trying to use the flask_socketio library, following the documentation: https://python-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html#what-is-socket-io

I have a file called socketio.py, and tried using their sample code:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
socketio = SocketIO(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app)
```

I get this error when trying to run it through python3 ($ python3 socketio.py)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "socketio.py", line 2, in <module>
    from flask_socketio import SocketIO
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask_socketio/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    import socketio
  File "socketio.py", line 2, in <module>
    from flask_socketio import SocketIO
ImportError: cannot import name 'SocketIO' from partially initialized module 'flask_socketio' (most likely due to a circular import) (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask_socketio/__init__.py)
```

When I tried using flask run to run it , I get this error

```
Error: While importing "socketio", an ImportError was raised:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python3.8/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 240, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "socketio.py", line 2, in <module>
    from flask_socketio import SocketIO
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask_socketio/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from socketio.exceptions import ConnectionRefusedError  # noqa: F401
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'socketio.exceptions'; 'socketio' is not a package
```

I have tried uninstalling socketio and reinstalling  and flask-socketio as there seems to be issues if you have both installed, but it still continues to give the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see you have named your program `socketio.py`. This is conflicting with socketio module used by `flask_socketio`. Rename your filename and try running.